# Enforcement of translational requirements for UK short term visitor visa from Italy

Tags: visas, uk, indian-citizens, italian-residents, translations

I am an Indian living in Italy and I am going to the UK for a leisurely family vacation for about 10 days.

Please note, this application is not very straight forward. There are four applicants, one applicant is applying from India another two are applying from Singapore and I am applying from Italy.

The checklist at the top has the statement

> all documents must be in English
>
> translated documents must be certified

I got the proof of accommodation from my commune, but it is in Italian. Getting it translated, isn't such a big deal as the commune itself provides multi-lingual certificates.

For the rest of the documents, this is an issue. Such as for "Evidence of being in education", my university provides an online certificate for this purpose which is in Italian.

Multiple acquaintances said that they provided their Italian house contract (in Italian) as proof of residency and no requirement came up for translation.

**Can anyone comment on how strict are they while enforcing the translational requirements of documents in respect to a short term visitor visa?**

Comment: Italians are covered by the EU Directive, visas are not required.

Comment: I am not Italian. I am an Indian citizen living in Italy with a residence permit.

Comment: Good work and thanks for the important update. Your answer is as follows: Indian nationals must play it strictly by the book, no exceptions, no discretionary latitude, full stop. All the rest is conjecture and somebody's opinion.

Comment: Just curious what your experience was? I am applying from italy for my non -EU partner and it's a minefield, expensive as hell for just a few days trip, and I am stressing big time. Did you get all your docs translated professionally or did you risk it?

Comment: My experience was that they don't really care so much as long as you provide the permit, passport, pay slips, bank statements and national identity card.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That all documents must be in English and that translations must be certified is not optional. The [UK Visa & Immigration supporting documents guide](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/visitor-visa-guide-to-supporting-documents/guide-to-supporting-documents-visiting-the-uk) is emphatic on that point:

> If you submit a document that is not in English or Welsh, it must be accompanied by a full translation that can be independently verified by the Home Office. Each translated document must contain:

- confirmation from the translator that it is an accurate translation of the original document
- the date of the translation
- the translator's full name and signature
- the translator's contact details

As it also point out, submission of these documents does not guarantee that your application will be successful. However, disregarding that requirement, on the advice of those to whom it may not apply, risks a refusal.